# Without modifying the JRE source code, is there a way to cause the Java VM to only execute local code?

Tags: java, security

It's my understanding that a lot of the Java VM security issues involve holes in the VM sandboxing mechanism that permit remotely sourced applications to break out and do naughty things to a client machine (not to be confused with a program someone downloads from the web and runs locally - in that case it's up to the user to make sensible choices about what to install and execute). As far as I can tell, the stock JREs available from Oracle are all hard-wired to allow the user to run code from the web. Is there some way to change this behavior? I checked the Java security settings and the 'max' setting still permits the execution of web-sourced code.

I'm asking because I'm working on a desktop application for which I'd like to take advantage of the extensive set of Apache language processing packages currently available. However, given all the security issues with Java, lots of folks are getting rid of it all together, which will hurt our ability to deploy the application to organizations with security policies that prevent Java from being installed on their computers.

So is there a pre-existing solution to this or am I going to have to hack a safer Java VM?

Comment: If nothing else helps, you could replace URLCLassLoader. But then, some malicious code could still download something and present the bytes as class ....

Comment: @DavidDaedalus When you are talking about "code from the web" do you actually mean an apache library?

Comment: You're talking about the client-side.  Making hack-proof applications for the client side is tough in any language, not just Java.  Part of the reason that there is so much interest in the "3-tiered application" is that the middle tier of services is under the software engineer's control and, therefore, more secure.

Comment: @mwhs sorry, thought I was clear on this point in the posting. What I'm taking about is forcing the VM to only execute Java applications that have been downloaded to the client computer as an executable jar and are intended to be run as client-side applications with all the access to client system resources any other desktop application has.

Comment: @scottb This is not to be confused with 'hack-proofing' which is inherently impossible. What I'm after is a way to side step the Java VM Sandbox vulnerabilities by not allowing anything that would normally run in the sandbox to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Java code that is "run from the web" is launched via the web browser. If you disable Java in the web browser, you've effectively disabled "running from the web".

Java provides instructions for [disabling "Java content in the browser" for all browsers](http://java.com/en/download/help/disable_browser.xml) at once via the Java control panel, and for disabling it in individual browsers. Hint: This works on both Windows and Mac.

One thing that you may find useful is that the currently recommended way of distributing Java desktop applications on the Mac is to include a full JRE in the application bundle, especially since Java web browser integration is disabled by default on the Mac. This way you're not even dependent on a JRE being installed on the OS.

If only Windows had application bundles, but you may be able to do something similar on Windows. As far as I understand, Java is self-contained in the JRE folders. It's not dependent on other programs or registry entries if you're not expecting browser integration. You should be able to copy a JRE to their hard drive and launch from there.

Locally bundled JREs like this would not be integrated with the operating system, web browsers would not be aware of them, and thus they would not provide the ability to "run from the web".

It's unfortunate that customers are not able to understand this distinction and refuse to install a JRE on the system, which is harmless by itself (with browser integration disabled). Yet, if they find out that you're "installing Java" on their system, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Capital idea! It didn't occur to me that JRE, simply resident in the filesystem, would do the job. Thanks, mate!

Comment: "Any Java code that is "run from the web" is launched via the web browser." - what about URLClassLoader? You simply can put things in the net in your classpath.

Comment: @Ingo, you have to already be executing code to use `URLClassLoader`. Any trusted, running program, could download code and run it. Many programs download a (signed) auto-updater from the web, then launch it with elevated privileges to update. This is not as bad as that. The classes that you load would run with the same privileges, within the same process. It was worth mentioning though. Thanks. The issue is the "launching" and  "from the web", not just "from the web".